# vim command to restructure/force text to 80 columns without combining

Tags: vim

I set my `textwidth` in vim as set `set textwidth=80`. When and use the key sequence <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to reformat the current line. However I would like to only add a break without combining lines.

Namely consider the text

```
   this is a line with new text. 
   A new second line
```

with `textwidth=16` there should be

```
this is a line 
with new text. 
A new second 
line
```

instead I get

```
this is a line 
with new text. A 
new second line
```

How can only add breaks without combing of lines for the whole file?

Comment: What key are you pressing after `gqg`.  `gqg` is a pending sequence.

Comment: `gqgq` would do the current line.

Comment: your expected output has different sentence than sample input, consider using same lines for clarity... also, if I am understanding correctly, you can use shell command `fold -s -w16`